# Conexion remota de PHP a SQL SERVER 2017 en Windows

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Hola tengo una pc donde está instalado appserver y alojada una aplicación donde funciona todo OK.

Quiero realizar querys a SQL SERVER que está en otro equipo fisicamente sin embargo me muestra el siguiete error

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client, or SQL Server 2008 Native Client, SQL Server 2005 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client, or SQL Server 2008 Native Client, SQL Server 2005 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] No se encuentra el nombre del origen de datos y no se especificó ningún controlador predeterminado [message] => [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] No se encuentra el nombre del origen de datos y no se especificó ningún controlador predeterminado ) )

Argregué los dll correspondientes a la carpeta de php y los active en php.ini y no funciona.

Instalé AppServer en el servidor donde se encuentra instalado SQL SERVER y configuré exactamente los mismo que en la otra pc y si me establece la conexión.

Alguna solución...

Comment: Hacer funcionar sql server en php es complejo, usando los dll de sqlserver suele dar problema. Intenta haciendo conexión con PDO ODBC o PDO DBLIB (este solo funciona en linux).

Comment: El error dice que faltan una serie de Clientes, y te pone unos enlaces de donde descargarlos. ¿Has probado ya con los enlaces?